# PHPMailer: Insert a signature block in an HTML email

Tags: php, phpmailer

I've been using PHPMailer without too many issues, but the last request I received had me spending hours without a solution.
No one else seems to have had that issue and not a single example can be found online.

We generate the HTML email in real time because it has to be populated by some calculated field, so no import from a file.
I've been asked to insert an ordinary signature with the usual standard prefix "-- ".
The problem is: no matter what I try, no email client recognizes the signature block.

I'm aware that it usually is just an ordinary dash dash space \n. No rocket science here. Yet...

Some solution I tried, sparsed:

```php
    $body .= "-- ";
    $body .= "-- <br>";
    $body .= "-- " . PHP_EOL;
    $body .= "<p>-- </p>";
    $body .= "-- \n";
    $body .= "-- \n<br>";
    $body .= "-- \n" . PHP_EOL;
    $body .= "<p>-- \n</p>";
    $body .= "--&nbsp;\n";
    $body .= "--&nbsp;\n<br>";
    $body .= "--&nbsp;\n" . PHP_EOL;
    $body .= "<p>--&nbsp;\n</p>";
    $body .= "--  \n";
    $body .= "--  \n<br>";
    $body .= "--  \n" . PHP_EOL;
    $body .= "<p>-- \n</p>";
    $body .= "-- \r\n";
    $body .= "-- \r\n<br>";
    $body .= "-- \r\n" . PHP_EOL;
    $body .= "<p>-- \r\n</p>";
    $body .= "--  \r\n";
    $body .= "--  \r\n<br>";
    $body .= "--  \r\n" . PHP_EOL;
    $body .= "<p>--  \r\n</p>";
```

And many more. Like 200 more.

Probably the answer is a simple thing that I missed, but I'm completely lost right now.

[ Sorry for my english ]

[EDIT]

1) What I expect from the client when it encounters the block -> that it recognizes it as a signature.
That means that Gmail will put "..." while Thunderbird (in my case and with my settings) would plain cut it in the reply.

Before: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2YaCK.png
After: https://i.stack.imgur.com/haWIi.png

2) Which clients did you check? -> Gmail and TB.

3) Manual check -> Yes of course. **My** email has one and I'm 100% certain that it works.

What I noticed in Gmail is that, in "Show original", an ordinary mail is like this one:

```
    *aaa*

    *dsadfv*
    vsdfv <http://www.google.com>
    fdvsdfv
    -- 
    dsfgsdfv
```

While mine is always a variation of this one:

```
    <br>-- =20
```

What I mean is that not a single line begins with the double dash but is always preceded but the previous line separator, plus it ends with =20 that Gmail uses as a return.

Comment: What do you expect a client to do when it encounters the `--`? What is not happening that you think should be?

Comment: Which clients did you check? Also, it would help if you shared a screenshot of such an email in the tested clients. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Have you checked these clients recognize a signature the way you want, when you insert this manually into an email? Have you checked the source code of the mail that was send using phpmailer, whether this was output 1:1 as intented - and not maybe got trimmed at some point, or something like that?

Comment: if you use html tags, you need to declare the correct MIME version and/or content-type, please add your $headers declaration to your post. See here: https://css-tricks.com/sending-nice-html-email-with-php/
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
Your body should start and end with the HTML tag (<html>)

Comment: Jasie of course I'm using HTML tags. I've been sending emails for a month.
And I'm not using mail() but phpmailer. 
Btw my charset is UTF-8 and encoding is 16bit - I tried changing both without a tangible result.

Comment: Sure. So you set $mail->isHTML(true)? It would be easier to help you if you posted more of your code - that is why I posted this link for you to follow: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I hope it doesn't sound rude because it's definitely NOT my intention, but I wrote HTML both in the title and in the description, specifying that it works like a charme.

Sadly I don't think I'm allowed to post code that I don't own since I've got no formal authorization.